# Detect when 2 recurring (time triggered) scripts will sync [Theoretical]

Tags: date, time, cron, synchronization, theory

This is a somewhat theoretical question. I have 2 CRON jobs that run in a staggered interval, one every 13 minutes, and the other every 15 minutes.

I know it's very easy to stop them running at the same time etc with locks/stops.

However it got me thinking in a theoretical sense, how the synchronisations in time; when they both run at the same minute could be visualised.

So far it's actually a pretty interesting logic, as it's a case of converting the 13 minutes and 15 minutes into similar 24 based hour formats, and then detecting if any of them match. This bit isn't too hard, and the basic logic I have sort of got in this jsFiddle (Very ugly and janky/long way around, but it sort of works): http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/kdo5bwk9/

I can't quite visualise how/when these sync/simultaneousness' will occur though (I know they WILL occur, I just don't know if that's day's/weeks/months apart etc).

This may possibly be a question I should ask on https://math.stackexchange.com/ but StackOverflow is my frequent, so I'll try here first.

As I said, this is not for any real world application, simply a maths logic that has intrigued me today.

TL:DR 2 "Things" running at 13 minutes and 15 minutes. At first it may seem simple, numbers that are divisible by both 13 and 15. Eg, we know they will both run at 9:30 eventually. But HOW OFTEN / regularly will the 13 min cycle hit 9:30 at the same time the 15 minute cycle hits 9:30 as it's likely to be ahead/behind most of the time.

```
@MrWigster
```

Comment: Lowest common denominator? (Forgive me if this is too obvious).